# Formula to set value on pick list based on user country

Tags: formula, custom-field, event, userrecordaccess

I have a question before using apex to accomplish this.
On the Event page layout I'm using a couple of custom fields; **Location_Country__c** and **Location__c**. These fields have a field dependency, *controlling field* is **Location_Country__c** and *dependent field* is **Location__c**.

I was trying to write a formula that will set a value on the controlling field Location_Country__c based on the country of the "**Assigned to:**" user.

I tried several things but can't get it to work, is this something possible or should I just look into an Apex trigger to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe you have to use apex to do that, as workflow does not allow us to calculate new value based on any formula in picklist.

There is actually idea for that:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpd7AAC

Comment: Thanks Artur, 
I saw that idea a few minutes ago but wanted to be sure that I couldn't do this using declarative tools before jumping to Apex.